# How to get the props from child component automatically to reduce duplicate code in component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my application, there is 2 component which have a lot of same props.

```
<DatePicker
  label="Start Date"
  value={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}
  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
  inputVariant="outlined"
  variant="inline"
  autoOk
  style={{ width: '100%' }}
/>

<DatePicker
  label="End Date"
  value={endDate}
  onChange={(date) => setEndDate(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}
  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
  inputVariant="outlined"
  variant="inline"
  autoOk
  style={{ width: '100%' }}
/>
```

Therefore, I create the following component to solve the problem.

```
function StyledDatePicker(props) {
return (
    <DatePicker
        label={props.label}  //I don't want to specify it every props in DatePicker
        value={props.value}  //I don't want to specify it every props in DatePicker
        onChange={props.onChange}  //I don't want to specify it every props in DatePicker
        minDate={props.minDate}  //I don't want to specify it every props in DatePicker
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        inputVariant="outlined"
        variant="inline"
        maxDate={moment()}
        autoOk
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
    />
  );
}
<StyledDatePicker
  label="Start Date"
  value={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}
/>
```

And you can see that I have to set "label={props.label}" within StyledDatePicker to get the props. Is there anyway that StyledDatePicker can auto detect the rest of the props?

Comment: why not just spread the props `...props`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), what it does is
destructuring an object or an array. So it acts like rewritting all the given props. You would get something like this

```
function StyledDatePicker(props){
return (
    <DatePicker
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        inputVariant="outlined"
        variant="inline"
        maxDate={moment()}
        autoOk
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

And if you want to make sure that the default props you specified are not getting overidden by the props object, you should specify it as the first prop of the component like this:

```
<DatePicker
            {...props}
            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            variant="inline"
            maxDate={moment()}
            autoOk
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your return, you can specify `const {label, value, onChange, minDate} = props`.

Comment: Thanks, this can reduce those 'props.'. But is there a way I can also reduce "const {label, value, onChange, minDate} = props" ?

Comment: In that case, you should go with the answers of @mahdi using the spread operator

Answer (score 0):

<Datepicker {...props} />